# Accessing Dictionary objects From Web Service returning SIGABRT

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, web-services

I have a table view in which each cell I'd like to have data populated in them from the web service. Each cell is supposed to display the name of the object,  the price, and the brand name. I can get the name fine, but the price and brand name aren't coming as easy. I checked the web service and it DOES have prices and brand names so it's definitely a problem with my code. Here's how it looks so far:

```
    for (NSDictionary *objItem in resultsArray)
{
     NSString *currentItemName = [objectTitlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([currentItemName isEqualToString:objItem[@"title"]])
    {
        cell.nameLabel.text = currentItemName;
        cell.priceLabel.text = objItem[@"price"];
        cell.brandLabel.text = objItem[@"brands"];

    }
}
```

objectTitlesArray is an array I made separately which contains the names of the objects that get returned, so that's why I can get the name easily.

Here is what is inside resultsArray:

```
<__NSArrayI 0x8cb9900>(
{
asins =     (
);
"best_page" =     {
    currency = USD;
    deeplink = "http://www.textbooks.com/iPhone-Book-Covers-iPhone-4S-iPhone-4-and-iPhone-3GS/9780321832764/Scott-Kelby.php";
    description = "\"Excellent Marketplace listings for \"\"iPhone Book: Covers iPhone 4S, iPhone 4, and iPhone 3GS\"\" by Scott Kelby starting as low as $1.99!\"";
    "image_url" = "http://images.textbooks.com/TextbookInfo/Covers/0321832760.gif";
    "in_stock" = 1;
    "live_price_url" = "http://api.invisiblehand.co.uk/v1/pages/live_price?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.textbooks.com%2FiPhone-Book-Covers-iPhone-4S-iPhone-4-and-iPhone-3GS%2F9780321832764%2FScott-Kelby.php";
    "original_url" = "http://www.textbooks.com/iPhone-Book-Covers-iPhone-4S-iPhone-4-and-iPhone-3GS/9780321832764/Scott-Kelby.php";
    pnp = "3.99";
    price = "24.99";
    "price_confidence" = low;
    region = us;
    "retailer_name" = "Textbooks.com";
    title = "iPhone Book: Covers iPhone 4S, iPhone 4, and iPhone 3GS";
};
brands =     (
    Pearson
);
categories =     (
);
eans =     (
    9780321832764
);
id = 10a9fb4e3868f5289dc0d53af80ae86a;
"image_url" = "http://images.textbooks.com/TextbookInfo/Covers/0321832760.gif";
isbns =     (
    0321832760
);
models =     (
);
mpns =     (
    0321832760
);
"number_of_pages" = 1;
resource = "/products/10a9fb4e3868f5289dc0d53af80ae86a";
title = "iPhone Book: Covers iPhone 4S, iPhone 4, and iPhone 3GS";
upcs =     (
);
},
```

All help is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

EDIT:

changed my code to this:

```
for (NSDictionary *objItem in resultsArray)
{
     NSString *currentItemName = [objectTitlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([currentItemName isEqualToString:objItem[@"title"]])
    {
        if (cell.priceLabel.text != (id)[NSNull null] && cell.priceLabel.text.length != 0 && cell.brandLabel.text != (id)[NSNull null] && cell.brandLabel.text.length != 0)
        {


        cell.nameLabel.text = currentItemName;
        NSDictionary *bestPageDictionary = objItem[@"best_page"];
        cell.priceLabel.text = bestPageDictionary[@"price"];
        NSArray *brandsArray = objItem[@"brands"];
        cell.brandLabel.text = [brandsArray firstObject];
        }

    }
}
```

And now am getting NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c98c00'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary structure does not match the data you're trying to get out of it.

- `brands` is an array, not a string. It does happen to contain a single string element, so you just need to grab that.

  ```
  NSArray *brandsArray = objItem[@"brands"];
  cell.brandLabel.text = [brandsArray firstObject];
  ```
- `price` is not in the top level dictionary but nested in another one inside it.

  ```
  NSDictionary *bestPageDictionary = objItem[@"best_page"];
  cell.priceLabel.text = bestPageDictionary[@"price"];
  ```

**Edit** Looks like the price may actually be a number even though it appears to be a string. Try this:

```
NSDictionary *bestPageDictionary = objItem[@"best_page"];
NSNumber *price = bestPageDictionary[@"price"];
cell.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", price];
```

Comment: so it looks like I'm getting objects now, because now I'm getting SIGABRT [NSNull length]

Comment: i added an if statement to check for null objects, and now it's crashing with NCSF number length or something

Comment: Looks like one of the values is actually an `NSNumber`, not an `NSString`, probably the price. Editing my answer, try that.

Comment: some of the prices show up as <null> on my tableviewcell. Anyway to fix it?

Comment: that most likely means the actual JSON value was null. You need to fix the data itself.

Comment: how do i fix the data?

Comment: You should open up another question which addresses this specific issue.